# Buttons won't hide in custom TabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, hide

using [this](http://www.rumexit.co.uk/2010/11/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-2-of-2/#comment-539) tutorial I set up a custom TabBar. Unfortunately the tutorial won't describe how to hide the custom TabBar in views you don't wanna display it.

In my `customTabBar.h` I defined

```
- (void) hideAlsoCustomTabBar;
- (void) showCustomTabBarAgain;
```

which are implemented as

```
- (void) hideAlsoCustomTabBar {

    btn1.hidden = YES;
    btn2.hidden = YES;
    btn3.hidden = YES;  
    btn4.hidden = YES;
}

- (void) showCustomTabBarAgain {

    btn1.hidden = NO;
    btn2.hidden = NO;
    btn3.hidden = NO;
    btn4.hidden = NO;
}
```

Calling those inside `CustomTabBar.m`'s `viewDidAppear` works fine and does exactly what I expect them to do. If I try to call those methods from the ViewController where I need to hide the TabBar like this

```
[customTabs hideAlsoCustomTabBar];
```

inside the `initWithNibName` OR `viewDidLoad` OR `viewWillAppear`, nothing will happen. I checked with NSLog, the method gets called, but when I read out the BOOL for any buttons `.hidden` attribute, it returns 0, when it should be 1 (for `hidden==YES`).
I don't know what's wrong with my setup. Is it possible these button's attributes are private by default as `CustomTabBar` inherits from `UITabBarController` and I can't set them? Or did I make a mistake in the call?

Thanks!
**EDIT**
The TabBar implementation as it is described in the tutorial

```
import "CustomTabBar.h"
@implementation CustomTabBar

@synthesize btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4;

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self hideExistingTabBar];
[self addCustomElements];
}

- (void) hideExistingTabBar {
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
        view.hidden = YES;
        break;
    }
}
}

- (void) addCustomElements {
//Initialise the two images for btnEinleitung, not selected and selected
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnEinl.png"];
UIImage *btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnEinl_s.png"];

self.btnEinleitung = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
btnEinleitung.frame = CGRectMake(0, 430, 86, 50);
[btnEinleitung setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnEinleitung setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected  forState:UIControlStateSelected];   
[btnEinleitung setTag:0];
[btnEinleitung setSelected:true];

//set other buttons
btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUbg.png"];
btnImageSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUbg_s.png"];
self.btnUebungen = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnUebungen.frame = CGRectMake(86, 430, 80, 50);
[btnUebungen setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnUebungen setBackgroundImage:btnImageSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnUebungen setTag:1];

   /* do the same for btn3 and btn4*/


//add custom buttons to view
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
[self.view addSubview:btn2];
[self.view addSubview:btn3];
[self.view addSubview:btn4];

//setup event handlers so the buttonClicked method will respond to the touch up inside event
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

//set tab to active according to the passed tag number 
- (void) selectTab:(int)tabID {
switch (tabID) {
    case 0:
        [btnEinleitung setSelected:TRUE];
        [btnUebungen setSelected:FALSE];
        [btnTipps setSelected:FALSE];
        [btnBrauchtum setSelected:FALSE];

        btnEinleitung.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        btnUebungen.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        btnTipps.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        btnBrauchtum.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        break;
    case 1:
        [btnEinleitung setSelected:FALSE];
        [btnUebungen setSelected:TRUE];
        [btnTipps setSelected:FALSE];
        [btnBrauchtum setSelected:FALSE];

        btnEinleitung.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        btnUebungen.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        btnTipps.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        btnBrauchtum.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        break;
// and so on for 2 and 3
    }
self.selectedIndex = tabID;
}

//get the tag of the sender/pressed button, call the function selectTab
- (void) buttonClicked:(id)sender {
int tagNum = [sender tag];
[self selectTab:tagNum];
}
```

**EDIT**
As described below, I have 4 Tabs in a Tabbar which was generated with IB, added Navigation Controller with their ViewControllers, made Outlets for those and connected them in IB.
Clicking on the second Tab (e.g. sndMenuVC) opens a view with 4 buttons. Clicking one of these buttons leads to another view (e.g. detailVC) in which I don't want the TabBar to be displayed. detailVC has it's own nib.
Opening detailVC happens with the button's action declared like this

```
- (IBAction) openFourth:(id)sender{
detailVC *detailView = [[detailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailVC" bundle:nil andSender:kFourthButtonSender];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
[detailView release];
}
```

As this is a custom initWithNibName, this is how I implemented it

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andSender: (NSString *)calledByButton{
self.callingButton = calledByButton;
[super initWithNibName:@"detailVC" bundle:nil];
return self;
}
```

SO I basically just set a global variable "callingButton" according to the transmitted sender and call the "normal" initWithNibName afterwards.

This all works fine.

If I try to call `hideAlsoCustomTabBar`, and NSLog the value of btn1.hidden it returns 0 when called from detailVC, but returns 1 when called from within CustomTabBar and actually hides the buttons.

I have customTabs as IBOutlet if needed, but don't know if this is connected correctly to the TabBarController of type CustomTabBar.

[image: IB Setup]

Hope this helps to understand me :) If you need any other information, just let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you got this working properly? you declare a method like `-(void) hideAlsoCustomTabBar;` and implement `- (void) hideAlsoCustomTabBar:(int)wert {`. This should've resulted in an error.

Comment: @Deepak Sorry, the :(int) wert was just for testing purposes inside my code, I don't need it and will edit my entry to fit it!

Comment: How is `customTabs` set?

Comment: @Deepak Inside the calling VC.h `IBOutlet CustomTabBar *customTabs;` and `@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet CustomTabBar *customTabs;`, inside the .m I synthesize it and used as described above.. Anything missing?

Comment: @Deepak Hm.. I checked with `if (customTabs == nil){NSLog(@"customTabs == nil");}` and it wrote the NSLog into the console. So that would be the problem. I assigned customTabs wrong.. How would I have done it right?

Comment: How are you initializing the view controllers.

Comment: @Deepak Did you mean the VC that don't need to display the custom TabBar? It's initialized with a custom InitWithNibName, as I need to know by which button of the parentVC this VC is called. In this custom initWithNibName I just set a global parameter to the sender for later referenece and than call the normal initWithNibName.

Comment: This is a bit too complicated to consume in a conversation. Can you post the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a follow up to my RXCustomTabBar tutorial which should answer your questions.  I don't see any point reproducing it in full here.

[Hiding your New Custom UITabBar (RXCustomTabBar follow up)](http://www.rumex.it/2011/07/hiding-your-new-custom-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application/#more-187)

Let me know if you have any questions,
Oli

Comment: This customized tabbar working properly but not for ARC if you are going to use ARC than it will not work. if you have any suggestions please give that.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to hide the tabBar you can simply, in your view controller, call

```
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: @Saphrosit Thanks for your fast reply. I had this before when I had the standard tabbar. As my new custom TabBar basically exists of 4 own buttons, just redirecting to the tabbar functionality, this line won't do the trick..

Comment: Your new custom tab bar should extend the default `UITabBar` and you should use the suggested solution, I think

Comment: @marzapower I'd love to use that simple line of code, I tried, but unfortunately it won't hide the buttons :/

Comment: Can you please post the code of your implementation of the tab bar? I mean the custom class you created.

Comment: @marzapower The tabbar implementation is the same as in the tutorial I've linked to. I'll add the code into my question though :)

Comment: In your implementation, the `viewDidLoad` method is calling `[super viewWillLoad ...`: this is kinda wrong, and you should check it!

Comment: @marzapower Thanks for pointing that out! I changed that locally. Unfortunately this won't fix the problem..

Comment: Doh! I will try it locally on my machine, when I have some spare time.

Answer (score 0):

In RXCustomTabBar.m file addCustomElements function is called from viewDidAppear.

```
-(void)addCustomElements
{
    .
    .
    .
    .


    // Add my new buttons to the view
    // Following lines are adding buttons to the view. Put your condition here according to requirement so that it will check and add buttons accordingly.
    [self.view addSubview:btn1];
    [self.view addSubview:btn2];
    [self.view addSubview:btn3];
    [self.view addSubview:btn4];

    .
    .
    .
    .

}
```

Hope this helps.

**Update**

```
//Add following function in RXCustomTabBar.m
-(void)hideButtons
{
    btn1.hidden = YES;
    btn2.hidden = YES;
    btn3.hidden = YES;
    btn4.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)selectTab:(int)tabID
{
    switch(tabID)
    {
        case 0:
            [btn1 setSelected:true];
            [btn2 setSelected:false];
            [btn3 setSelected:false];
            [btn4 setSelected:false];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self hideButtons]; //Call function for hiding buttons like this.
            [btn1 setSelected:false];
            [btn2 setSelected:true];
            [btn3 setSelected:false];
            [btn4 setSelected:false];
            break;
    }   
    self.selectedIndex = tabID;
}
```

Let say you want to hide buttons on 2nd View Controller. So I have called [self hideButtons] in case 1 index.

This will Hide all the tabbar buttons. And again Viceversa you have to put diff condition to show those tab buttons.

Does this make sense ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood that piece of code, but I'm not sure what your suggestion is. addCustomElements gets called when the App launches, but I need the buttons to be hidden after another button (none of the tabbar-buttons) is pressed, so I need self.btn1.hidden = YES; and so on the be available from a method that I can call..

Comment: @Nareille I have updated my answer. Plz try to implement like that.

Comment: It's like that I don't need the TabBar to be hidden when a Tab is pressed, but when another Button, implemented in another view is pressed. So to check for the tabID is not what I need, but to be able to call  `hideButtons` from outside the class..

Answer (score 0):

Since the custom tabs exists already at the point this method is called. You should assign it to `detailView`'s `customTabs` property here.

```
- (IBAction) openFourth:(id)sender{
    detailVC * detailView = [[detailVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailVC" bundle:nil andSender:kFourthButtonSender];
    detailView.customTabs = **theExistingCustomTabsObject**;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
    [detailView release];
}
```

**Orignal Answer**
As the reference to the subclass of the `UITabBarController` is `nil`, you will have to set it properly. If you have used IB to set the view controllers, go to the NIB file. Right click on the view controller, select the `customTabs` outlet and connect it to the `customTabBar` object holding the view controllers.

If you've created the view controllers programmatically then somewhere after adding the view controllers to the tab bar and before releasing the view controllers, do this,

```
viewController.customTabs = self.customTabBarObject;
```

Comment: @Deepak Sorry, I'm a little confused. My setup is like there are 4 Tabs. tapping on the second, the view shows 4 buttons. Tapping on one of this buttons will open another view, in which I don't want the custom TabBar (or the normal one) to be shown. I added the tabbar and it's tabs, aka the Navigation Controller with the ViewController via IB, declared them programmatically and connected the Outlets accordingly in IB. I had to render the custom Tabs (Buttons) programmatically like described in the tutorial.. I'll try to post an simplified code of what I have in my question. That may take a sec

Comment: @Deepak I edited my question, hoping that was what you needed to know. I tried the IB connection and set up a Controller therefor, but it didn't change a thing, probably I did it wrong. I guess I would need the programmatically approach, but again I'm not sure how to do it right.. Calling it inside `addCustomElements` with `sndVC.customTabs = self....` I don't know what to add after self. the custom buttons? Doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say `hideAlsoCustomTabBar` is a method in `CustomTabBar` but I don't see it in the updated definition. However your `customTabs` seems to be properly connected. That second part was valid only if the view controllers were set programmatically. So you can ignore `self.customTabBarObject`. Do you create the `viewControllers` again anytime?

Comment: Ok, although this is a bit confusing for me, I think you are creating the view controllers on button tap. Since the button tap is handled within the `CustomTabBar` object, you should do `viewController.customTabs = self;`.

Comment: @Deepak I didn't add `hideAlsoCustomTabBar`as its implementation is stated above, so I thought that would be unnecessary.. If you say `viewControllers`, do you speak about the one that's supposed to hide the TabBar (detailVC) or the CustomTabBar-Controller? I create the instance of CustomTabBar (customTabs) inside detailVC. detailVC is more often instantiated throughout the project.

Comment: If `detailVC` is supposed to be the NIB name, why do you have the `CustomTabBar` object set up in `MainWindow.xib`?

Comment: @Deepak I create the detailVC on a button tap, but not on a tabbar-button tap, but from a normal rect button inside the view (`- (IBAction) openFourth:(id)sender`) So the line `viewController.customTabs = self;`would go inside the CustomTabBar.m like inside the viewDidLoad, right?

Comment: @Deepak detailVC is the ViewController and the NIB has the same name. I have the original TabBar in the MainWindow.xib as I need it on most of the views. I also tried to connect customTabs from detailVC(nib) by dragging in a "object" and set it to be of the class CustomTabBar and gave it the customTabs Outlet.

Comment: @Deepak If I set `detailVC.customTabs = self;` inside `viewDidAppear` of `CustomTabBar.m` I can check, that it is not nil when I enter detailVC's `viewDidLoad`. Trying to manipulate the buttons than will fail though, either through `[customTabs hideAlsoCustomTabBar]`as well as through `customTabs.btn1.hidden = YES`.. Does that help?